# Is it correct to say "It's over/ more than/ past 10 pm but you still haven't gone to bed"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

How do we express time when we don't care too much about the exam time, for example,

"**It's over/ more than/ past 10 pm but you still haven't gone to bed**" or

"**It's almost / nearly 11 pm but you still haven't gone to bed**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first sentence, "past" is the only correct one of option. You could also say "after".

For your second sentence, both options are correct.

Note that, in informal conversation, you would not say "pm". If it's in the evening, and you are talking about now, just saying "ten" will be interpreted correctly.

Comment: "It's gone ten" is also idiomatic